# Jquery Cycle - Um slide centralizado e as outras duas aparecendo parcialmente

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, cycle2

Estou precisando de um slider que teria pelo menos 3 slides, onde o do meio apareceria completamente com a resolução e os outros dois laterais apareceriam parcialmente.

Estou usando a solução **Cycle2** http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Eu preciso que ele funcione corretamente no **IE8** para cima.

Estou tentando implementar, mas não está funcionando corretamente. O exemplo está localizado em http://theva.com.br/teste/index2.php. Quando ajusto o tamanho da janela, a mudança não acompanha, fica como se estivesse estático.

Tentei simplificar o máximo possível, estava usando um outro plugin, porém não funcionou corretamente no IE e passei muito tempo tentando resolver, então decidi usar outro plugin.

Comment: Quando você diz "fica como se estivesse estático" se refere ao fato de que ele não centraliza quando muda o tamanho? Aqui ele nem fica centralizado, somente quando a janela fica perto de 1080px de largura.

Comment: isso cara, na realidade teria que estar centralizando em qualquer resolução

Answer (score 1):

Como estou precisando entregar para hoje, fiz outra solução com o Cycle2 e no IE 8 e 9 só vai aparecer apenas um slide, o resto fica vazio mesmo, foi a maneira mais rápida para visualizar corretamente... já já eu subo no ar com as alterações que fiz....

Nos restos dos navegadores estou usando o BXslider mesmo